# How to fetch all list of object records

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on converting a procedural php code to mysqli OOP the code below returns all users based on joined information

```
   public static function find_all_users()
    {
        $db = getConn();

        $stmt = $db->prepare("
         SELECT * 
         FROM users 
         JOIN roles 
         WHERE roles.role_id = users.role_id 
         ORDER BY created_at");

        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user->fetch_object();
    }
```

When I do a var_dump it gives me and object, however  on the page to display it i call

```
$users = User::find_all_users();
```

Then

```
<?php if (!empty($users)) : ?>

    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2><?= $user['name'] ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?= $user['email'] ?></p>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<?php else : ?>

    <p>No User found.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If i try to use **$this->id**  or **$user->id**  it tells me I am trying to get a non object but when I **var_dump $users** it returns a object?

```
object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'id' => int 1
  public 'name' => string 'bigjah' (length=4)
  public 'email' => string 'tester@local.com' (length=22)
  public 'password' => string '$2y$10$TOPc3JHjtoxfJQI14EMRj.ybVkgEPo4KB6.yB5s6pK/PHWO1GOaDy' (length=60)
  public 'created_at' => string '2021-09-25 01:32:38' (length=19)
  public 'about' => null
  public 'ip_address' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  public 'reset_token' => null
  public 'reset_key' => null
  public 'confirmed' => string '857795025069' (length=12)
  public 'verified' => int 0
  public 'role_id' => int 4
  public 'role_title' => string 'Administrator' (length=13)
```

Comment: `fetch_object` returns a single object from the current row. You probably want `fetch_all` or `fetch_array`

Comment: @ChrisHaas if i do that then I cannot use $this->id or $user->id only $user['id'] is that not bad in OOP?

Comment: OOP is a programming paradigm. What matters is whether code works or doesn’t work. Your functions name implies that it returns a collection (array) of something. Whether that “something” is an object or a sub array doesn’t really matter. Don’t force OOP onto something, use it if/when it makes sense to you.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you I am new to OOP I had lots of questions but no answers so it dont matter if it uses $this->    if i used an array and used $row['id'] it would still be clean

Comment: `$this` is used when you are inside of a class. When you are outside, `$this` no longer exists. OOP is not faster, better, cleaner, etc., those are just opinions by people. If you don’t get OOP, don’t use it. That said, there’s a trend towards it so I’d look for a good and thorough tutorial on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I have to point out that this would be easier if you were using PDO instead of mysqli. I highly recommend considering an upgrade.

The reason why it doesn't work for you is that `User::find_all_users();` returns a single object, not an array of objects. This means that you return only a single user.

If you would like to return an array of objects (each one representing a single user) you can collect them into an array like this:

```
public static function find_all_users(): array
{
    $db = getConn();
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * 
        FROM users 
        JOIN roles 
        WHERE roles.role_id = users.role_id 
        ORDER BY created_at");
    
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->get_result();
    
    // populate the array with users
    $return_array = [];
    while($user = $results->fetch_object()) {
        $return_array[] = $user;
    }

    return $return_array;
}
```

```
    <?php foreach (User::find_all_users() as $user) : ?>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2><?= $user->name ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?= $user->email ?></p>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you would like to return just an array of arrays (which is simpler if you are not using PDO) then you can simply call `fetch_all()`:

```
public static function find_all_users(): array
{
    $db = getConn();
    
    $stmt = $db->prepare("
        SELECT * 
        FROM users 
        JOIN roles 
        WHERE roles.role_id = users.role_id 
        ORDER BY created_at");
    
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->get_result();

    // return all rows as associative arrays
    return $results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

```
    <?php foreach (User::find_all_users() as $user) : ?>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h2><?= $user['name'] ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?= $user['email'] ?></p>
                </div>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a single object, if that dump is the result of dumping **$usrs**. Therefore, change the way you fetch the statement into `$st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);` if you are using PDO. But I see that you are not so `$user -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

To use the result of your query as an object

```
while ($user = find_all_users()): ?>
     <h2><?= $user->name ?></a></h2>
}
```

That means you loop every time you get an instance of the object from your current function.

Comment: You were on the right track with this answer, but the while loop does not look right. `$user` will be a multidimensional array and it will only iterate once. You'd have to use `foreach`, which OP is using so I have no idea why you changed it to `while`

Comment: Yes, that was my first suggestion. But OP implied he didn't want the associative array but an oop approach. Hence, I thought he can keep his function, which returns one instance of an object every time it is called.

Comment: Yeah, that is not going to work. Try it yourself. This will always show the same user record.